# Regex value between 2 strings

Tags: c#, regex

How do I get the value in between 2 strings?  I have a string with format d1048_m325 and I need to get the value between d and _.  How is this done in C#?

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: Will everytime you will be required the string between d and _ only. or that will be different in different cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(?<=d)\d+(?=_)
```

should work (assuming that you're looking for an integer value between `d` and `_`):

```
(?<=d) # Assert that the previous character is a d
\d+    # Match one or more digits
(?=_)  # Assert that the following character is a _
```

In C#:

```
resultString = Regex.Match(subjectString, @"(?<=d)\d+(?=_)").Value;
```

Comment: And remember that precompiled regexes are a valuable source of proteins. :)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively if you want more freedom as to what can be between the d and _:

```
d([^_]+)
```

which is

```
d       # Match d
([^_]+) # Match  (and capture) one or more characters that isn't a _
```

Comment: This would grab 'nonum' in dnonum_. Can only be used if value sought can be non-numerical.

Comment: Yes.... that's what I meant by more freedom.  It was never specified whether the value was numerical so I was just giving more options :)

Answer (score 1):

Even though the regex answers found on this page are probably good, I took the C# approach to show you an alternative. Note that I typed out every step so it's easy to read and to understand.

```
//your string
string theString = "d1048_m325";

//chars to find to cut the middle string
char firstChar = 'd';
char secondChar = '_';

//find the positions of both chars
//firstPositionOfFirstChar +1 to not include the char itself
int firstPositionOfFirstChar = theString.IndexOf(firstChar) +1; 
int firstPositionOfSecondChar = theString.IndexOf(secondChar);

//the middle string will have a length of firstPositionOfSecondChar - firstPositionOfFirstChar  
int middleStringLength = firstPositionOfSecondChar - firstPositionOfFirstChar;

//cut!
string middle = theString.Substring(firstPositionOfFirstChar, middleStringLength);
```

Comment: I know that Substrings/indexOfs are faster than regular expressions.  I'd be interested to know how two IndexOfs and a Substring compared to one regex in C# though.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use lazy quantifier

> d(\d+?)_